# How to iterate through more than one nuke node class using nuke.allNodes() in a for loop?

Tags: python, nuke

nuke.allNodes() can filter for one specific node class i.e. nuke.allNodes("Transform"). But how to do it if i want to have it filter more? Some work around?

perhaps place them in:  var = []

But how do i access lets say motionblur value in a example (this dose not work):

```
for i in var:
    print i.knob("motionblur").value() #Transform nuke node class
    print i.knob("samples").value() #ScanlineRender nuke node class
```

Thank you.

Comment: Iterate through a list of Nuke node types and call the function on each type? I haven't looked at Nuke's API, but perhaps there's a method that supports this already.

Comment: I just started learning python, but i searched for this in the internet for days and in the Nuke's help documentation.. i could not find anything. perhaps i don't know what to search for.. or is there some work around?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little confused because in your code you have `i.knob("motionblur")`. The string in `.knob()` should be a name of a knob not the name of a node type.

I would suggest iterating through all the nodes and checking the type of each node. Then do whatever you need to on that type of node.

```
for i in nuke.allNodes():
    if i.Class() == "MotionBlur":
        #DO SOMETHING
    elif i.Class() == "Transform":
        #DO SOMETHING
```

If you are doing the same thing to both types of nodes, you could merge two lists and iterate over it.

```
n = nuke.allNodes("MotionBlur")
n.extend(nuke.allNodes("Transform"))
for i in n:
    #DO SOMETHING TO BOTH TYPES
```

I don't know what you are specifically trying to achieve, so this may not be the most efficient method.